# C/C++: What does this syntax mean?

Tags: c++, c, syntax

What does `sampler2D texture0 : DEFINESAMPLER(0);` do? It's taken from a header inside a game's directory. I'm confused about the use of the colon.

---

**Edit:** More context, as requested.

There really isn't much more context to mention. The line is from a file *resources/Shaders/ShaderMacros.h* from a game called *Super Meat Boy* (the Steam version, at least). The header just contains a bunch of declarations such as the one I mentioned above:

```
/**
Defines for profile specific compiling 
*/
#define DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(x) register(c##x)
#define HardwareInstanceTrans float4x4 matInstanceTransform : TEXCOORD1
#define HardwareInstanceTexCoordOffset float4 vInstanceTexCoordOffset : TEXCOORD5

#ifdef SHADER_DX
    #define matrixmul(mat, pos) mul(pos, mat)
#else
    #define matrixmul(mat, pos) mul(mat, pos)
#endif


#define DEFINESAMPLER(x) register(s##x)

/*************************************************************
SAMPLERS
*************************************************************/
sampler2D texture0 : DEFINESAMPLER(0);
sampler2D texture1 : DEFINESAMPLER(1);
sampler2D texture2 : DEFINESAMPLER(2);
sampler2D texture3 : DEFINESAMPLER(3);
sampler2D texture4 : DEFINESAMPLER(4);
sampler2D texture5 : DEFINESAMPLER(5);
sampler2D texture6 : DEFINESAMPLER(6);
sampler2D texture7 : DEFINESAMPLER(7);
sampler2D texture8 : DEFINESAMPLER(8);
sampler2D texture9 : DEFINESAMPLER(9);
sampler2D texture10 : DEFINESAMPLER(10);
sampler2D texture11 : DEFINESAMPLER(11);
sampler2D texture12 : DEFINESAMPLER(12);
sampler2D texture13 : DEFINESAMPLER(13);
sampler2D texture14 : DEFINESAMPLER(14);
sampler2D texture15 : DEFINESAMPLER(15);

/*************************************************************
VERTEX SHADER CONSTANTS
*

************************************************************/
float4x4 matWorld : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(0);         //Uses 4 registers

#ifdef SHADER_DX
float3x4 mat3x4TexGen0 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(4);    //Uses 3 registers
float3x4 mat3x4TexGen1 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(7);    //Uses 3 registers
float3x4 mat3x4TexGen2 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(10);   //Uses 3 registers
float3x4 mat3x4TexGen3 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(13);   //Uses 3 registers
float3x4 mat3x4TexGen4 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(16);   //Uses 3 registers
float3x4 mat3x4TexGen5 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(19);   //Uses 3 registers
float3x4 mat3x4TexGen6 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(22);   //Uses 3 registers
float3x4 mat3x4TexGen7 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(25);   //Uses 3 registers

float3x4 mat2x4TexGen0 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(28);   //Uses 2 registers
float3x4 mat2x4TexGen1 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(30);   //Uses 2 registers
float3x4 mat2x4TexGen2 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(32);   //Uses 2 registers
float3x4 mat2x4TexGen3 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(34);   //Uses 2 registers
float3x4 mat2x4TexGen4 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(36);   //Uses 2 registers
float3x4 mat2x4TexGen5 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(38);   //Uses 2 registers
float3x4 mat2x4TexGen6 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(40);   //Uses 2 registers
float3x4 mat2x4TexGen7 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(42);   //Uses 2 registers
#else

/** Texture coord generation matricies */
float4x3 mat3x4TexGen0 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(4);    //Uses 3 registers
float4x3 mat3x4TexGen1 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(7);    //Uses 3 registers
float4x3 mat3x4TexGen2 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(10);   //Uses 3 registers
float4x3 mat3x4TexGen3 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(13);   //Uses 3 registers
float4x3 mat3x4TexGen4 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(16);   //Uses 3 registers
float4x3 mat3x4TexGen5 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(19);   //Uses 3 registers
float4x3 mat3x4TexGen6 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(22);   //Uses 3 registers
float4x3 mat3x4TexGen7 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(25);   //Uses 3 registers

float4x3 mat2x4TexGen0 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(28);   //Uses 2 registers
float4x3 mat2x4TexGen1 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(30);   //Uses 2 registers
float4x3 mat2x4TexGen2 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(32);   //Uses 2 registers
float4x3 mat2x4TexGen3 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(34);   //Uses 2 registers
float4x3 mat2x4TexGen4 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(36);   //Uses 2 registers
float4x3 mat2x4TexGen5 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(38);   //Uses 2 registers
float4x3 mat2x4TexGen6 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(40);   //Uses 2 registers
float4x3 mat2x4TexGen7 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(42);   //Uses 2 registers

#endif

/***
Graphics Pipeline stuff
*/

//ColorConstant1
float4 cColorConstant1 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(0);    //uses 1 register
float4 cColorConstant2 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(1);    //uses 1 register
float4 cColorConstant3 : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(2);    //uses 1 register

float4 vShaderParams : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(3); //uses 1 register

float4 cFogColor : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(4); //uses 1 register
float4 vFogParams : DEFINEFLOATCONSTANT(5);

#define FOGMAXDIST vFogParams.x //this parameter is CPU calculated as 1 / elementZ. This is only applicable for 2D
#define FOGITEMDIST vFogParams.y //item distance set by the CPU
```

Comment: As Alexandre says, more context is needed. The problem is that the C preprocessor can redefine what sampler2D, texture0 and DEFINESAMPLER all mean. And without knowing where you got these names from, we can't usefully comment further.

Comment: this is not C or C++, it's some shader language.

Comment: That doesn't appear to me to be C or C++. Could you give an example of where `ShaderMacros.h` is referenced via `#include` ?

Comment: @unapersson I added all the context I am able to provide.

Comment: @Alexandre C Please check my edited post. I added some more details.

Comment: @Rob Adams No, I cannot. This is the only *.h file in that directory and it seems to serve as configuration. The game I took it from is not open source.

Comment: Holy macro hell batman ... `DEFINESAMPLER` is a macro of register so that code is registering your various `sample2D` variables named texture0 through texture15 by their integer ids. P.S. this looks like it came from the Ogre engine which is open source and OpenGL if I recall.

Comment: it may be a shader language which is then processed into C++ via a smart preprocessor. To me it doesn't seem sane C++.

Comment: @AJG85: yes but then why the colon symbol ?

Comment: @Stefano because this is not C++ it's pre-processor code specific to the graphics library he's using. This is not a file he should need to look at really.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a C or C++ header file.  This is a HLSL shader file.  In short, the `sampler2D texture0 : DEFINESAMPLER(0);` statement creates a texture input into the shader.  For more information about HLSL see [MSDN HLSL Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509561%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like that headerfile gets preprocessed and then gets included in the actual shader files.

```
sampler2D texture0 : DEFINESAMPLER(0);
```

For example expands to

```
sampler2D texture0 : register(s0);
```

after preprocessing. That texture sampler then gets assigned to a sampler register `0`. Look at [this msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd607359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.